# WebSocket disconnected when trying to send large size of images

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, websocket

I am testing a WebSocket at localhost using java and javascirpt, running Tomcat 7.0.42 and no proxy in between. It works fine on sending text and small size of image via websocket. However, it will be forced to close the connection on client side(chrome browser) when trying to send a large size of photo (**Notice that the tomcat's 'onClose callback in MessageInbound' does not be notified after websocket on browser closed the connection**).

how can I solve it? thx.

[Here is the capture from chrome development tool](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3hbk4zyo7r93if/Capture.JPG)

Below is my code on client side:

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // step 1: tell server who the people you want to send
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        action: "binary",
        receiver: <%=selectedfriend.getUserId()%>,
        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
   }));

   // step 2: send file
   ws.send(f);

   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
       return function(e) {
           var span = document.createElement('span');
           span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" style="width: 50px;height: 30px;" src="', e.target.result,
           '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
           appendImage(span.innerHTML, "pullleft");
       };
   })(f);
   reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution for my question, what i did on Tomcat is to use:

```
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String string, HttpServletRequest hsr) {

    MyMessageInbound inbound = new MyMessageInbound();

    inbound.setByteBufferMaxSize(9999999);
    inbound.setOutboundByteBufferSize(9999999);

    return inbound;
}
```

But there is another problem is:
what is the proper value I should use, here is 9999999, the value should be tested well when I upload under 8-9MB file using WebSocket, but why, how can I measure it?
Please help and discuss here again, thx!

Answer (score -1):

Try to send as ArrayBuffer:

```
ws.send(f.readAsArrayBuffer());
```

Comment: still there is a data size limit on web socket.