# JavaScript client failed to send WebSocket frame to WebSocket server on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I have a web socket server running on an Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 Instance. My web socket server is written in Python, I am using Autobahn WebSockets.

I have a JavaScript client that uses WebRTC to capture webcam frames and send them to the web socket server.

My webserver (where the JavaScript is hosted) is not deployed on EC2. The python web socket server only do video frame processing and is running over TCP and port 9000.

**My Problem:**

The JS client can connect to the web socket and the server receives and processes the webcam frames. However, after 5 or 6 minutes the client stops sending the frames and displaying the following message:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://x.x.x.x:9000/' failed: Failed to send
>   WebSocket frame.

When I print the error data I got "undefined".

Of course, this never happens when I run the server on my local testing environment.

Comment: It turned out that the problem is not because the server running on Amazon EC2. After more testing, the problem only occur when the JS client is running on Google Chrome. If the client running on FireFox, this problem doesn't exist. Not sure about the source of the problem yet. As soon as I figure out the source and the solution I will update the post.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by to a Chrome Extension.

Comment: I am not sure. I found that chrome drop the connection. I capture 5 frame per seconds and send them to the server. for some reason if I change the image format from JPEG or PNG to webp chrome does not drop the connection and I can keep sending video frames from the client browser to the cloud server for up to 12 hours without. It is clear something about the data size (image size) I am not sure how chrome handle page or process memory. See this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583948/websocket-disconnected-when-trying-to-send-large-size-of-images) indicate similar issue

Comment: I agree - it could easily be a memory issue related to the size of the data and a buffer building up. It may be worth looking at the Chrome Dev Tools under the Profile section to see if the memory use is unstable over time.